# JS equivalent of curl -X PUT -d 'data={"keyname":"keyvalue"}'

Tags: javascript, curl, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to use XMLHttpRequest to send a PUT request but I'm not sure how to pass arguments.

The curl version of what I want to send is :

```
$ curl -u me@myurl.com -X PUT -d 'data={"keyname":"keyvalue"}' https://api.myurl.com/v1/action
```

I've got an auth token to make calls so what I'm trying is this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("PUT", ROOT_URL + link + "?auth_token=" + token, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
var data = 'data={"keyname":"' + keyvalue + '"}';
xhr.send(data);
```

But that doesn't seem to be correct because I get a 500 server error back which says

```
 "data={\"keyname\":\"keyvalue\"}" does not have a valid root.
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might have to set the `Content-Type` request header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (so that the server knows how to interpret the data).

Comment: Just read the CURL `man` page and it says that the content type header is set automatically to that value when using `-d`. So that could be indeed the problem. But note that the server might also directly accept JSON, in which case you really just want to send `JSON.stringify(some_object)` and set the content type header to `application/json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because  `"data={\"keyname\":\"keyvalue\"}"` does not represent a valid json object.

Try using

```
  xhr.send({keyname:keyvalue});, passing a valid json object
```

Or

```
  var data = {keyname:keyvalue};
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));, passing a json object string representation
```

Comment: ["There is no such thing as a JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). What you are passing is a JavaScript object and it will most likely be converted to the string `[object Object]`. If you want to send JSON, you have to convert the object to JSON, has you show in your second example. In JavaScript, `{keyname:keyvalue}` is an object, not JSON. Besides, the OP seemed to successfully sent `data={"keyname":"keyvalue"}` with CURL.